# Choose set of TDs conditionally with Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Say I have:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">           
        <td>{{row.field1}}</td>
        <td>{{row.field2}}</td>
        <td>{{row.field3}}</td>

        <td>{{row.field4}}</td>
        <td>{{row.field5}}</td>
        <td>{{row.field6}}</td>
</tr>
```

Now I want a conditional where I pick either field1-3 or field4-6.. So right now it's:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">           
        <td ng-if='row.isFirst'>{{row.field1}}</td>
        <td ng-if='row.isFirst'>{{row.field2}}</td>
        <td ng-if='row.isFirst'>{{row.field3}}</td>

        <td ng-if='!row.isFirst'>{{row.field4}}</td>
        <td ng-if='!row.isFirst'>{{row.field5}}</td>
        <td ng-if='!row.isFirst'>{{row.field6}}</td>
</tr>
```

Which, when I have many columns is annoying... I'd like to somehow have the conditional outside the actual "td" Like:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">           

    <% if row.isFirst { %>
        <td>{{row.field1}}</td>
        <td>{{row.field2}}</td>
        <td>{{row.field3}}</td>

        <% else { %>

        <td>{{row.field4}}</td>
        <td>{{row.field5}}</td>
        <td>{{row.field6}}</td>

        } %>
</tr>
```

kinda like underscore... But it seems that angular doesn't support outside conditionals only conditionals on elements. Any ideas?

Comment: Make an ng-repeat for the headers and another for the rest of the table? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve exactly but it would probably be easier to modify your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to give you the “angular way” or the MVVM way, not exactly the "technical trick" you may be expecting.

Angular is an MVVM framework and therefore all your “logic” should be in the controller or the services but **not** in the View(html).

What you are trying to achieve is to display:

```
Model1 ={ Column1: ‘a’, Column2: ‘b’, Column3: ‘c’}
```

Or

```
Model2 ={ Column4: ‘d’, Column5: ‘e’, Column6: ‘f’}
```

If you think in terms of the models and the view you will find that is much simpler separating and performing these actions in your controller and having a lighter view which is also in the nature of the MVVM way to resolve this.